# Connecting MS Infopath with Siebel CRM On Demand using Web Services

Tags: soap, infopath, credentials, siebel, ondemand

I have to create  a form where I want to send customer id to CRMOD and and should get customer address…customer contacts.

I did but when i click on Run Query button it gives me error:

The SOAP response indicates that an error occurred on the server:

Server
SBL-ODU-01006Internal Error: Session is not available. Aborting.

How to avoid this.How can i pass my Siebel Credentials.How can i see the SOAP request tht MS Infopath is sending????
PLZ HELPy

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you either don't have an active session, or you didn't include the credentials in the soap request header.

I am not sure how you do that in MS Infopath, but this is how SOAPUI adds it.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:acc="urn:/crmondemand/xml/account" xmlns:ns="urn:crmondemand/ws/account/10/2004" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>USERNAME</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">PASSWORD</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">ICC4Ho6oURr/yaJI9uN/+Q==</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2013-04-11T22:07:18.772Z</wsu:Created>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:AccountWS_AccountQueryPage_Input>     
         <acc:ListOfAccount>
            <acc:Account>
              .....
            </acc:Account>
         </acc:ListOfAccount>
      </ns:AccountWS_AccountQueryPage_Input>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```